# disjoint unions in C,Pascal and SML

Tags: c, pascal, sml, disjoint-union

I was studying about disjoint unions in programming. I came across with the saying that `Pascal`,`SML` and `C` have their own union version: `variant record`,`construction` and `union`. It was also saying that `Pascal` contains a "tag" that you don't have to use it, `SML` has a tag that you required to use it and `C` does not have a tag. furthermore, `SML` will throw exception if we used it wrong, `Pascal` allows check during runtime and `C` does not have a feature for checking during runtime and the programmer have to add a field for a "tag" manually.

First of all, I don't understand what is "tag". I was trying to look at some examples of those unions but didn't understand what "tag" represents. If "tags" are important, how come `C` does have one? what is the difference between those unions.
Also, I didn't find any material related to the "tag" of unions. 
Futhermore, what does it mean "checking during runtime", checking what? It will be great to see smiple examples that show those features.

Comment: It's probably talking about record-keeping to inform which member-type the union is storing.

Answer (score 2):

One could call such disjoint unions a very early form of polymorphism. You have one type that can have several forms. In some languages, which of these forms is being used (is active) is distinguished by a member of the type, called a tag. This can be a boolean, a byte, an enum, or some other ordinal.

In some (older?) versions of Pascal, the tag is actually required to contain the correct value. A Pascal "union" (or, as they are called in Pascal, *variant record*) contains a value that distinguishes which of the branches is currently "active".

An example:

```
type
  MyUnion = record  // Pascal's version of a struct -- or union
    case Tag: Byte of // This doesn't have to be called Tag, it can have any name
      0: (B0, B1, B2, B3: Byte);  // only one of these branches is present
      1: (W0, W1: Word);          // they overlap each other in memory 
      2: (L: Longint);
  end;
```

In such versions of Pascal, if Tag has the value 0, you can only access B0, B1, B2 or B3 and not the other variants. If Tag is 1, you can only access W0 and W1, etc...

In most Pascal versions, there is no such restriction and the tag value is purely informative. In many of those, you don't even need an explicit tag value anymore:

```
MyUnion = record
  case Byte of // no tag, just a type, to keep the syntax similar
    etc...
```

Note that Pascal variant records are not pure unions, where each part is an alternative:

```
type
  MyVariantRec = record
    First: Integer; // the non-variant part begins here
    Second: Double;
    case Byte of // only the following part is a "union", the variant part.
      0: ( B0, B1, B2, B3: Byte; );
      1: ( W0, W1: Word; );
      2: ( L: Longint);
 end;
```

In C, you would have to nest a union in a struct to get something nearly the same:

```
// The following is more or less the equivalent of the Pascal record above
struct MyVariantRec
{
    int first;
    double second;
    union
    {
        struct { unsigned char b0, b1, b2, b3; };
        struct { unsigned short w0, w1 };
        struct { long l };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag is anything that tells you what member of the union is currently being used.
It's usually an enum but could be an integer, a boolean, or a bitfield based on one of these.

Example:

```
union my_union { char *string; void *void_ptr; long integer; };

struct my_tagged_union {
    union my_union the_union;
    enum { is_string, is_void_ptr, is_integer } the_tag;
};
```

C not forcing you to use a builtin-tag means you have more control over the layout and size of your data. For example you can use a bitfield tag and place it next to other bitfield information you store in your structure so that the bitfields get merged, yielding you space savings; or sometimes the union member currently in use is implicit from the context your code is in, in which case no tag is needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, I don't understand what is "tag".

Wikipedia has [a reasonably nice discussion of the overall concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), which starts off with a list of synonyms, including "tagged union".  Actually, "tagged union" is the main heading of the article, and disjoint union is one of the synonyms.  It starts with a pretty succinct explanation:

> a data structure used to hold a value that could take on several
>   different, but fixed, types. Only one of the types can be in use at
>   any one time, and a **tag** field explicitly indicates which one is in
>   use.

You go on to ask,

> If "tags" are important, how come C does have one?

How important tags are in this context is a language-design question on which C, Pascal, and SML take different positions.  Inasmuch as C is inclined to take a rather low-level approach to most things, and to allow users a great deal of control, it is not surprising that it does not force tag usage.  Users who want tags can implement them themselves with comparative ease, as indeed I have done myself on occasion.

Alternatively, it might be easier to say that C *doesn't have* tagged unions as a built-in language feature at all, only plain, untagged unions.  From that perspective, if you want a tagged union in C then you have to implement it yourself.  This is probably the most consistent view, but I gather that it differs from the one presented in the material you have been studying.

> what is the difference between those unions.

They are different implementations of a similar concept, provided by different languages.  A full analysis would be beyond the reasonable scope of an SO answer.  Like many things in Computer Science and elsewhere, the *abstract idea* of disjoint unions can be realized in a great many different ways.

> Also, I didn't find any material related to the "tag" of unions.

See above, and the linked Wikipedia article.  I'm sure you could turn up a lot more material, too, especially with WP's synonym list to work with.

> Futhermore, what does it mean "checking during runtime", checking what?

I'd have to see the context and exact statement to be sure, but it seems likely that your source was talking about checking one or more of these things:

- that the tag of a particular instance of the union is one of those defined for that union type, or
- that the contents of the union are of the type indicated by the tag, or
- that a list of alternative actions (see below) covers all possible alternatives.

> It will be great to see smiple examples that show those features.

My Pascal is too rusty to be of any use, and I do not know SML.  Even just a C example may be instructive, however:

```
enum my_tag { INT_TAG, STRING_TAG, DOUBLE_TAG };

union disjoint_union {
    struct {
        enum my_tag tag;
        int an_int;
    };
    struct {
        enum my_tag tag_s;
        char *a_string;
    };
    struct {
        enum my_tag tag_d;
        double a_double;
    };
};

union disjoint_union u =  { .tag = INT_TAG,    .an_int = 42 };
union disjoint_union u2 = { .tag = STRING_TAG, .a_string = "hello" };
union disjoint_union u3 = { .tag = DOUBLE_TAG, .a_double = 3.14159 };
```

This being C, the tag is provided manually and explicitly, and the language does not distinguish it specially.  Also, it is up to the programmer to ensure that the union's content bears the correct tag.

You might use such a thing with a function like this, which relies on the tag to determine how to handle instances of the union type:

```
void print_union(union disjoint_union du) {
    switch (du.tag) {
        case INT_TAG:
            printf("%d", du.an_int);
            break;
        case STRING_TAG:
            printf("%s", du.a_string);
            break;
        case DOUBLE_TAG:
            printf("%f", du.a_double);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> SML has a tag that you required to use it *[...]*. furthermore, SML will throw exception if we used it wrong,

Standard ML has [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) which contain *sum types* and *product types*. The *sum types* build on top of unions (and the *product types* build on top of structs), but handle what you call a tagged or disjoint union automatically in the compiler; you specify the *constructors*, and the compiled code figures out how to differentiate between the different constructors via *pattern matching*. For example,

```
datatype pokemon = Pikachu of int
                 | Bulbasaur of string
                 | Charmander of bool * char
                 | Squirtle of pokemon list
```

So a *sum type* can have different constructors with different parameters, and the parameters can themselves be a product of other types, including sum types, and including the type being defined itself, making the data type definition recursive. This is implemented with tagged unions, but the abstractions on top provide for more syntactic convenience.

To clarify, Standard ML will not throw an exception if used wrong, but throw a *type error* during compilation. This is because of [Standard ML's type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system). So you can't accidentally have a `(void *)`-pointer that you cast to something it isn't, which is possible in C.